# JENA error TurtleParseException when executing JAR

Tags: java, parsing, jena, executable-jar

I made a program that parses **turtle files** with **Jena library**. These are the dependencies i use:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-iri</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

So the parsing is **working well on my java program** but when i create my **jar** and try to run it, i have these kind of errors :

```
ERROR JenaService:146 - org.apache.jena.n3.turtle.TurtleParseException: Line 28015, column 79: org.apache.jena.iri.impl.IRIImplException:
<http://www.reussir.fr,> Code: 28/NOT_DNS_NAME in HOST: The host component did not meet the restrictions on DNS names.
```

Any ideas ?

---

EDIT

[image: ScreenShot from my IDE]

I have a warning for the invalid IRI problem by running my program with the IDE, but still giving me errors with the generated jar.

Comment: The better dependency is org.apache.jena:apache-jena-libs:3.11.0 <type>pom</type>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the only dependency i really needed was **jena-arq**, so i removed others dependencies (especially **jena-iri** which was throwing the TurtleParseException) and the bad-iri errors became warnings like in the IDE execution logs.

Answer (score 0):

`<http://www.reussir.fr,>`

There is a comma in the URI in a place where commas are not allowed.

It is better to find and fix the data problem because it can lead to other problems later if not fixed.

Comment: thanks for answering, so yes i saw that some of my data contains invalid URIs but i'm surprised that my program works on intelliJ but fails when i execute the jar of this same program.

Comment: You seem to be using the old N3-related Turtle parser (legacy only), not the current one access via `RDFDataMgr`. Have you by chance repackaged the jena code? If so: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html

Comment: I don't think i have repackage anything but i tried to build my jars in different ways (building artifact is not working) so i added a maven-assembly-plugin in my pom that made me the jar i executed and gave me some errors instead of warning (fyi, i edited my post)